# Editor Missing on magento 2 content page

Tags: magento-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKIoD.png)

Editor option is miising on magento 2 admin content->page->edit content Tab

Answer (score 0):

its default magento issue 
you can try to get it by hard refresh same page 
or by deleting var -> cache and var -> page_cache